# How to obtain a new value immediately after a react asynchronous setState

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to immediately print and obtain new values after asynchronous setState, similar to the following：

```
export default function useStateCallback<T>(init: T): [T, (newValue: T, callback?: CallbackFunction<T>) => void] {
  const [state, setState] = useState<T>(init);
  const callbackRef = useRef<CallbackFunction<T> | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(state);
    if (callbackRef.current) {
      callbackRef.current(state);
      // callbackRef.current = null;
    }
  }, [state]);

  const setStateWithCallback = useCallback((newValue: T, callback?: CallbackFunction<T>) => {
    setState(newValue);
    if (callback) {
      callbackRef.current = callback;
    }
  }, []);

  return [state, setStateWithCallback];
};

const [videoSwitchs, setVideoSwitches] = useStateCallback<VideoEnhanceField[]>(['superResolution']);
const [audioSwitches, setAudioSwitches] = useStateCallback<AudioEnhanceField[]>([]);
const clearEnhanceSwitch = () => {
​    const stack = [];
​    if (!options.value.includes('video')) {
​      stack.push(
​        new Promise((resolve) => {
​          setVideoSwitches([], () => {
​            resolve(true);
​          });
​        })
​      );
​    }
​    if (!options.value.includes('audio')) {
​      stack.push(
​        new Promise((resolve) => {
​          setAudioSwitches([], () => {
​            resolve(true);
​          });
​        })
​      );
​    }
​    return Promise.all(stack);
};

async function submit() {
    if (!canSubmit) {
      return;
    }
    // setSubmitLoading(true);

    await clearEnhanceSwitch();
    console.log(videoSwitchs, audioSwitches);  // console old value
}
```

The idea is to customize a statecallback hook and modify the setState method to accept the second parameter callback function. This callback function does not need to do anything but ensure that the asynchronous setState has been completed when it is triggered, and then use promise packaging to achieve the effect of obtaining new values immediately by printing with await. However, this is not feasible. Why is this

Please help me provide a solution

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! I'm somewhat confused by what you are trying to do: why do you want to use `setState` and `useCallback` in non-React code?

Comment: Hi, I just pasted some of the code. In fact, the entire code is written in a tsx file, which is a React application